# How to Remove zeros after decimal points while using Round function in RDLC Reports?

Tags: asp.net, rdlc

I am Using RDLC Expression for rounding of my data to 4 decimals. but if i use 'Round' function it will show zeros after decimal point if the data has no decimal values.

Ex: If my value is 1 it shows 1.0000.
How to remove zeros?

My Expression: `=Round(CDec(Fields!ExchangeRate.Value),4)`

I need number without decimal point as whole number, if it has decimal values then it should display with decimal values.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`=Format(CDec(Fields!ExchangeRate.Value),"#.####")`

Above Expression Works fine. Thank You.

Comment: This will remove the 0. Eg. 0.1234. It will become ".1234". Any solution?

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Simply try this...it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the Format property of the textbox as

```
1- right click the textbox
2- click number
3- select Number from the category
4- set Decimal Places to 0
```

hope it will help you
regards